# Cambie la funcion de un comando por una variable

Tags: python

Recien estoy comenzando en el lenguaje de python, lo que pasa es que sin darme cuenta puse lo siguiente: print = 78 y se me cambio la función de dicho comando, por lo que no se como devolverlo a su funcion original.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola, saludos colega, consulta. Podrías adjuntar tu código completo para saber cual es el problema real?

Comment: Hola colega, acabo de subir una imagen con respecto al problema

Comment: estas recién empezando, te recomiendo usar visual studio code como editor. la verdad a veces la sintaxis y el flujo varia en un poco relaciona a los tipo notebook (colab, jupyter) y te puede resultar confuso...

Comment: agrego además de que no utilices palabras reservadas del lenguaje como nombres de variables, suele generar errores de este tipo...saludos

Comment: Nunca uses palabras reservadas para tus variables y funciones.

Comment: Tienes que subir el código completo (como texto, no imagen) para analizar el problema

Comment: Podés guardar la función original en otra variable antes de hacer print = 78. En realidad es un poco más complejo, pero digamos que estarías "renombrando" a la función. Otra (recomendada) cambia el nombre de tu variable como te indicaron en la respuesta. Por cierto, por que no te funcionó???

Answer (score 1):

La forma más simple de recuperar la función `print` es borrando la variable que has creado que la está enmascarando:

```py
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>> print = 12
>>> print
12
>>> del print
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>> print("Hola, mundo!")
Hola, mundo!
>>>
```

Si observas, la función `print` es una función *built-in*. Todas las funciones y variables *builtins* se pueden acceder siempre como parte de módulo `__builtins__`:

```py
>>> print = 12
>>> print
12
>>> __builtins__.print(f"Valor: {print=}")
Valor: print=12
>>> print = __builtins__.print
>>>
```